# bx slider vertical scroll jumping and other issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using bx slider to create an auto, vertical scrolling slideshow. I am currrently having two issues:

1. It jumps quite a bit when it gets back to the first slide.
2. After three or four cycles, the last slide rolls out of the div and then the screen is white for a good three or four seconds and the scroll begins at the bottom again. So a giant blank space in the scroll basically after about three or four passes.

What kind of things do I need to look for here to diagnose and solve this problem? Pseudo code of what I am using:

```
$('#example_container').bxSlider({
      mode: 'vertical',
      ticker: true,
      tickerHover: true,
      tickerSpeed: 1500,
      displaySlideQty: 3
    });

<div id ="example_container">
   <div class ="example_slide">
     //contents
   </div>
   <div class ="example_slide">
     //contents
   </div>
   <div class ="example_slide">
     //contents
   </div>
   <div class ="example_slide">
     //contents
   </div>
   <div class ="example_slide">
     //contents
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is wath you what, but this is an endless vertical slider:

http://jsfiddle.net/SK4dq/

you just set your html/css code.